# How can I increment PWM resolution for PMSM FOC control?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver, pmsm, vector-control

The pwm resolution effect torque ripple value.  My motor should be turn low speed . When the motor is turning slowly , the effect can be seen barely. I have 1024 pulse encoder per tour . The hardware is constant(maybe can be implementing hardware filter). How to improve pwm resolution?

Comment: There is no relation between encoder and PWM resolutions. PWM resolution is the minimum  change your hardware/software can make to the duty cycle

Comment: I calculated per phase duty cycle with encoder (electrical angle) and phase currents. If Encoder resolution is quite low , is it effect my pwm duty change range?